# Add "active" class attribute to clicked item in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add the 'active' class attribute on the clicked item only. So far I have a state attribute called activeItem:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { clickedNotebookId: '', activeItem: false };
}
```

I change the state to true inside the click function:

```
renderContent(event) {
    this.setState({clickedNotebookId: this.props.id, activeItem: true}, function(){
        //display content
    });
}
```

In my render() method I do the follow:

```
<div className="list-group">
    <a href="#" className={this.state.activeItem == true ? 'list-group-item active' : 'list-group-item'} onClick={this.renderContent}>{this.props.title}
    <button className="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="button" onClick={this.deleteNotebook}>
        <strong>x</strong>
    </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

-

```
className={this.state.activeItem == true ? 'list-group-item active' : 'list-group-item'}
```

I know the condition above is wrong because it activates all the items when clicked. Ideally it should only highlight the clicked item.

Answer (score 1):

You should either check for an `id` of the item that was being activated or maybe do it in the more "reactish" way and make it as component that takes props like `id` and `isActive`.
When clicked, the child will pass upward to the parent the child's `id`, this will allow the parent to store the current active id in the state.
When the parent will re-render the children items with a loop, it will check to see if the current active item id is equal to the current item's id inside the current iteration. If it does, then it will pass the `isActive` prop of the child as `true`.
It's the child's responsibility to render it self accordingly.

Example:

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

class MyItem extends React.Component {
  renderContent = e => {
    const { itemId, renderContent } = this.props;
    renderContent(itemId);
  };

  deleteNotebook = e => {
    const { itemId, deleteNotebook } = this.props;
    deleteNotebook(itemId);
  };

  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.props;
    const groupItemClass = `list-group-item ${isActive && "active"}`;
    return (
      <div className="list-group">
        <a href="#" className={groupItemClass} onClick={this.renderContent}>
          {this.props.title}
          <button
            className="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-danger"
            type="button"
            onClick={this.deleteNotebook}
          >
            <strong>x</strong>
          </button>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  renderContent = id => {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`rendering content for item id - ${id}`);
    this.setState({ activeItem: id });
  };

  deleteNotebook = id => {
    // do something..
  };

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          items.map((item) => <MyItem renderContent={this.renderContent} deleteNotebook={this.deleteNotebook} itemId={item} isActive={activeItem === item} />)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time grasping this. Can you please explain the less-reactish way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

The `activeItem` property is sort of 'global' meaning it is **not associated with a particular item**. When a Click event occurs, the 'global' property `activeItem` is changed to `true` meaning that for every item you check the `activeItem` for, all will be `true`. Hence, all the items would highlight.

Hence, you have to create separate component for each item and manage a local state